# Boundaries of integration - 3 dimensional

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, 3d

**Question**

> Let D be the region in the first octant that is bounded below by the
>   cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and above by the sphere $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2 = 1$. 
>   Set up an iterated triple integral to evaluate this volume.

I was trying to use cylindrical coordinates and ran into a slight doubt. Would the boundary for the angle be from $0 \to \pi/2$ since we should only consider the volume with both x and y positive?

Comment: I agree. Dou you know the boundaries for the second coordinate?

Comment: I believe so. I think $z$ would range from $r$ to $\sqrt{1-r^2} + 1$, and $r$ would range from $0$ to $1$

Comment: @Stockfish sorry forgot to tag you